# There is a issue with constraint layout with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Here is the code i used for `ConstraintLayout`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.lokeshlabs.filterableexample.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_movie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the layout item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_movie_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="movie name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="22sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_year"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="year"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output i got

[image: Here is the output i got]

When i change this to `Linear layout` or `relative layout` it is working fine

with linear layout code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lokeshlabs.filterableexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_movie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output when i use above code

[image]

even tried all the ways inside `constraintlayout` but no use may be it's a bug

Comment: share your custom layout for RecyclerView item

Comment: it is working good when i use `linearlayout `

Comment: share your adapter or it's layout

Comment: i just edited it

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or ⌘+K to properly format your source code chunks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use width and height as 0dp if you are setting view relative to parent in `constraintlayout`.

Note this "`MATCH_PARENT` is not recommended for widgets contained in a `ConstraintLayout`. Similar behavior can be defined by using `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to parent" in the documentation of the developer site.

Try this layout.This should help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_movie"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: let me try that too

Comment: It is useful can you tell me why definetly need to use `0dp`

Comment: As I added the explanation above it is adviced now in contraint layout to avoid match parent.The constraint layouts child views should use values in dp so that computation in all screen sizes will be easy

Comment: adding match parent doesnot give you specific size while computing

Comment: Yes I can help you in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160071/discussion-between-lokesh-kanumoori-and-anonymous).

Comment: @Anonymous Can you look in some what same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47606380/7062071)