# Row item of recycle view in Constraint layout collapse instead taking parent width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

Recently, I started using Constraint layout but today encountered very strange behaviour using it. When I am using RelativeLayout as root instead of ConstraintLayout in fragment_holiday.xml output is as expected but I want to know what is wrong with ConstraintLayout. My code is as follows for fragment,item_row

And I am getting output with constraint layout as(And on scrolling it is showing different beheviour as you can see in screenshot I am sharing) ---
[image]

fragment_holiday.xml

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.thepsi.psidashboard.Fragments.HolidayFragment">

    <com.thepsi.psidashboard.CustomViews.CustomDatePicker
        android:id="@+id/customDatePicker_holiday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:dateFormat="MONTH_YEAR"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view_holiday"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/general_margin_eight_dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/customDatePicker_holiday" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_holiday.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="24 - January - 2017"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Saturday"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Mahavir Jayanti"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView25"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Expected Design -

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Check the width of recycler view. Give "matchparent"

Comment: @ArnoldBrown Yes it worked!!!!!!! But why the hell it is written in docs that **MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this...

Change the **width** of **recyclerview** as **matchparent**

Yeah! as per the documentation the **widget** in **ConstraintLayout** doesn't support **matchparent** as **width**.

We have to assign the **width** as **0dp** and use **constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"** and **constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"** to reflect **matchparent** like you used.

But the solution I gave will work on some cases as you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to to update the item_holiday.xml like the below xml. I just added three labels and added their constraint properties. 
You will need to edit the label propertied as per your requirement.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I dont want View to have fixed dimens as you given. I am updating my answer with expected design.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="24 - January - 2017"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView26"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Saturday"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Mahavir Jayanti"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView25" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thaks for replying. No sucess :( now it looking like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1JCo5b7hiDE/WifGJhvxo2I/AAAAAAAABjQ/MFqm0eIqWj0rh0651cdO3tR29UfClsXuQCL0BGAYYCw/h1920/2017-12-06.png).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with height and vertical constraints in a recycler view and finally ended up using new support library version 27.0.2 and constraint-layout version 1.1.0-beta4 to get expected behavior.
Recommend everyone to bump to those versions if having some weird behaviors in constraint layouts.