# Android Studio: Items in RecycleView "jumps" to the left

Tags: java, android

I am working on the RecycleView, but I've encountered something weird. I am writing some simple application and here's the code of my custom row in RecycleView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewGameName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FirstTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewPrices"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SecondTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonRemove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="usuń"
        android:layout_weight="0">

    </Button>
```

On the display, it looks quite okay: [image]

But whenever I launch this application, something goes wrong and it looks like this: 
[image]

Because of some reason, the button jumps to the left side and I have no idea why. I don't post here any piece of code other than layouts because I don't think it's anyhow related to the problem itself, but I can attach it if necessary. Thanks in advance for help.

EDIT:
My Adapter code:

```
package com.ja.myboosterproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class BoosterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BoosterAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView gameNameTextView;
    public TextView pricesTextView;
    public Button removeButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        gameNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewGameName);
        pricesTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewPrices);
        removeButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonRemove);
    }
}

private List<com.ja.myboosterproject.Booster> mBoosters;
private Context mContext;

public BoosterAdapter(Context context, List<Booster> boosters){
    mContext = context;
    mBoosters = boosters;
}

private Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}

@Override
public BoosterAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.booster_list_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contentView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BoosterAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
    Booster booster = mBoosters.get(position);
    viewHolder.gameNameTextView.setText(booster.getGameName());
    viewHolder.pricesTextView.setText(booster.getPriceBought() + " - " + booster.getPriceSold());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return mBoosters.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post more code regarding how you are inflating the row. I'm guessing that the row doesn't have the parent layout params which means it doesn't extend to the full parent's width.

Comment: e.g. post your recyclerview adapter code

Comment: that's not true lol, linearlayout will cover the entire width of the parent with `layout_width="match_parent"`...

Comment: @Jin I've just added Adapter Code

Comment: @0X0nosugar - Jin is right, I've tried adding weights to the other LinearLayout and it still does not help.

Comment: These may help you debugging: [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html), [Show layout bounds](http://tysmith.me/post/27035355999/layoutbounds)

Comment: @EugenPechanec - thank you very much, LayoutInspector was really helpful in figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've finally got it. Thanks to @Eugen Pechanec (I wish I knew how to mention you properly), because The Layout Inspector showed me that there is something wrong. So, that was the code for my recycle view itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/layout_boosters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I used ContraintLayout and everything looks alright. But when I check The Layout Inspector - something is wrong: 
[image]
There are big areas of unused space even though all LinearLayouts are set "match_parent". So I decided to change ConstraintLayout to LinearLayout and bingo, it worked. I have no idea why RecycleView doesn't want to cooperate with ConstraintLayout, I hope that someone explains it, but my problem is solved.

EDIT: Found a solution:
Actually, a lot of people had the same issue and here I've found the solution that allows ConstraintLayout and RecyclerView work together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673523/8786284

Comment: The link in your edit is correct, but I had no idea it can affect children of children of constraint layout.